# Iterating permission requests on Android

Tags: java, android

I am using AIDE to make an android app. I figured it would be easier for me to iterate through a list of permissions since there are so many. My current code is giving no errors, it's just simply not working. All it is supposed to do so far is iterate through and check all the permissions listed in a string and if they are not granted it is supposed to request them.

My Current Code:

```
package blah.blah.blah;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_MULTIPLE = 1;

    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        "android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS",
//Other permissions 
        "android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" 
    };

    private Map<String, Integer> permissionRequestCodes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        checkAndRequestPermissions();
    }

    private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        permissionRequestCodes = new HashMap<>();

        // Check each permission
        for (String permission : PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionsNeeded.add(permission);

                // Assign a unique request code for each permission
                permissionRequestCodes.put(permission, generateUniqueRequestCode(permission));
            }
        }

        // Request permissions
        if (!permissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                permissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[0]),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_MULTIPLE
            );
        } else {
            // All permissions already granted
            proceedWithApp();
        }
    }

    private int generateUniqueRequestCode(String permission) {
        // Generate a unique request code based on the permission string
        return permission.hashCode();
    }

    private void proceedWithApp() {
        // Do something with the app after all permissions are granted
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_MULTIPLE) {
            boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                String permission = permissions[i];
                int grantResult = grantResults[i];

                if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = false;
                    Log.d("Permission", permission + " denied");
                }
            }

            if (allPermissionsGranted) {
                // All permissions granted
                proceedWithApp();
            } else {
                // Handle the case when some permissions were denied
            }
        } else {
            // Handle other permission request codes if needed
            Integer permissionRequestCode = permissionRequestCodes.get(permissions[0]);

            if (permissionRequestCode != null) {
                // Handle individual permission request result
                handlePermissionRequestResult(permissionRequestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handlePermissionRequestResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // Find the permission that matches the request code
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];

            if (requestCode == permissionRequestCodes.get(permission)) {
                int grantResult = grantResults[i];

                if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("Permission", permission + " granted");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Permission", permission + " denied");
                }

                // Handle the permission request result for this specific permission if needed
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app opens but it does nothing.